# Error in loading NLTK resources: "Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n\n"

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, word2vec

I adapted the following code from Susan Li's [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568), but incurred an error when the code tries to tokenize text using `NLTK`'s resources (or, there could be something wrong with "keyed vectors" loaded from the web). The error occurred on the 5th code block (see below, might take a while to load from the web):

```css
## 1. load packages and data

import logging
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import sent_tokenize
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
nltk.download('stopwords')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2w7iqi7c92uztt/stack-overflow-data.csv?dl=1')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['tags'])]

my_tags = ['java','html','asp.net','c#','ruby-on-rails','jquery','mysql','php','ios','javascript','python','c','css','android','iphone','sql','objective-c','c++','angularjs','.net']

## 2. cleaning

REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):

    text = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").text # HTML decoding
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # delete stopwors from text
    return text
    
df['post'] = df['post'].apply(clean_text)

## 3. train test split

X = df.post
y = df.tags
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)

## 4. load keyed vectors from the web: will take a while to load

import gensim
word2vec_path = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
wv = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_path, binary=True)
wv.init_sims(replace=True)


## 5. this is where it goes wrong

def w2v_tokenize_text(text):
    tokens = []
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text, language='english'):
        for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent, language='english'):
            if len(word) < 2:
                continue
            tokens.append(word)
    return tokens
    
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42)

test_tokenized = test.apply(lambda r: w2v_tokenize_text(r['post']), axis=1).values
train_tokenized = train.apply(lambda r: w2v_tokenize_text(r['post']), axis=1).values

X_train_word_average = word_averaging_list(wv,train_tokenized)
X_test_word_average = word_averaging_list(wv,test_tokenized)


## 6. perform logistic regression test

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)
logreg = logreg.fit(X_train_word_average, train['tags'])
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_word_average)
print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, test.tags))
print(classification_report(test.tags, y_pred,target_names=my_tags))
```

**Update on part 5** (per `@luigigi`'s comments)

```css
## 5. download nltk and use apply() function without using lambda

import nltk
nltk.download()
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import sent_tokenize

    def w2v_tokenize_text(text):
        tokens = []
        for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text, language='english'):
            for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent, language='english'):
                if len(word) < 2:
                    continue
                tokens.append(word)
        return tokens
        
    train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42)

    def w2v_tokenize_text(text):
    tokens = []
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text, language='english'):
        for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent, language='english'):
            if len(word) < 2:
                continue
            tokens.append(word)
    return tokens
    
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42)

test_tokenized = test['post'].apply(w2v_tokenize_text).values

train_tokenized = train['post'].apply(w2v_tokenize_text).values

    X_train_word_average = word_averaging_list(wv,train_tokenized)
    X_test_word_average = word_averaging_list(wv,test_tokenized)

## now run the test

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5)
logreg = logreg.fit(X_train_word_average, train['tags'])
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test_word_average)
print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, test.tags))
print(classification_report(test.tags, y_pred,target_names=my_tags))
```

This should work.

Comment: is this the full error traceback?

Comment: Nope, the error message is quite long, I will print it out. Please refer to the updates.

Comment: did you try to run `nltk.download()` before anything else?

Comment: I actually placed that after `STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))` in the load packages and data section.

Comment: did you try to run it without `'stopwords'` argument? the tokenizer seems to miss `punkt` or `english` data. try `nltk.download()` or `nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: The error message now says `KeyError: ('post', 'occurred at index 478')` (if I inserted `nltk.download('punkt')` at the very beginning.

Comment: thats a different issue. check your data format.

Comment: Still couldn't figure out what's going on and keep getting the error message.

Comment: try sth like this: `test_tokenized = test['post'].apply(w2v_tokenize_text).values`

Comment: @luigigi, it works, many thanks! I will post the updated code after getting back from a short break. Would you be able to post this as an answer entry (plus some explanations), so I mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then [nltk tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) expects the [punkt](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=punkt#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt) resource so you have to download it first:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Also, you dont need a `lambda` expression to apply your tokenizer function. You can simply use:

```
test_tokenized = test['post'].apply(w2v_tokenize_text).values
train_tokenized = train['post'].apply(w2v_tokenize_text).values
```